# Outlook 2013 constantly utilizes on cpu core

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I recently upgraded to MS Outlook 2013. And since then Outlook utilizes one CPU core all the time.

I use IMAP and I suspected the IMAP connector because I have seen a lot of complaints on IMAP in Outlook 2013 but my Outlook uses the CPU even if I set it to offline mode and disconnect the computer from network.

I have tried to disable all add-ins but it does not help.

Any ideas how to force Outlook to do not use cpu so much?

Comment: Upgrade to outlook 2016 helped finnaly.

Answer (score 1):

Now in 2020 and using Outlook 365 I had the very same problem: high CPU utilization from Outlook (according to Process Explorer about 12% of the CPU time was used by Outlook). My laptop’s fan was permanently on even if no other program was running.

What helped in my case (after quite some time struggling with this) was to remove the local cache *.ost file in between two Outlook sessions. CPU usage now is typically less than 1%.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: Outlook 2013 was constantly using 20-30% of my CPU. The only way to lower CPU usage was closing and re-opening Outlook 2013.

Following hints from two Microsoft blogs (see [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macoutlook/outlook-2016-cpu-usage-running-continuously-at/73ed13d4-8005-404a-8eeb-e7c1c918eadf) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6391c445-687d-4029-a4e2-bdc96f9b996e/outlook-2013-high-cpu-usage?forum=outlook)) I solved the problem removing a lot of old follow-up (marking them as 'completed'). This brought CPU usage back to 0%.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help me. When I restart outlook then the processor utilization is 25% (one core) almost immediately when the outlook starts. Meanwhile I migrated to web interface because I was not able to solve the problem.

Comment: skier, oh fun!! drummer, oh cool!! programmer, ha ha!! LOL

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a fix but addresses the symptom:

I noticed if you disable the reading pane the Outlook.exe process cpu load drop to zero.

**View** -> **Reading Pane** -> **Off**

**Also make sure all of your email windows are closed.**  Once you start reading an email the CPU spike comes back.  Really weird.

Comment: I tried to switch off the reading pane but it has no effect to CPU consumption. Outlook still consumes 100% of one CPU core.

Comment: I noticed this too after some time.  Not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.  Outlook would sit there idling but consuming 25% CPU (a whole CPU core).  I discovered that taking Outlook offline would stop it happening so figured it was something to do with re-syncing.  After a lot of playing about, I found that if I deleted all my cached/offline calendar entries and then let it re-sync the problem went away.  You delete the offline stuff by going to File->Options->Calendar, then clicking on the "Free/Busy Options" button and then in that dialogue, on the "General" pane, there is a button saying "Clear Offline Items".